# How can I turn off iTerm2 growl notifications for new output but keep them for rspec results

Tags: rspec, notifications, growl, iterm, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 (Build 2.0.0.20150412) and Growl (v2.1.3). I've got 'Enable growl notifications' selected for my profile as I use it with `rspec` and `growl_notify` when I'm writing code.

Is there a way to turn off the notification for new output received in tab as seen in the screenshot but keep the rspec notification?

[image: new output tab and rspec notification both showing]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually in the Growl preferences. In the Applications tab, you can enable / disable several notification types, including New Output.

[image: Growl Preferences]

Answer (score 2):

On **El Capitan** it's:

- Growl > Applications Tab > iTerm (double click or select `configure`)
- Notifications SubTab > and then click on the `Notification` dropdown
- Select `New Output` and uncheck `Enable`

Nice and simple, right?

[image: growl iTerm preferences]

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences/Notification/iTerm , you can enable / disable several notifications.
[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDYiw.png)